# How to get notified to change (Edit, not remove or add) in one of the objects properties of ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, observablecollection

We have observable collection(OC) bound to listView which has two text-boxes in windows 8.1 app. We have implemented InotifyPropertyChaged. When we edit value in textbox, its setter is fired but setter of OC doesn't get fired means OC doesn't get updated automatiocally. CollectionChanged event of OC gets fired only during addition, removal, clearing list.

We want to to update OC as soon as one of its object properties get modified/edited. Is it possible by OC?

We have also come across BindingList which updates automatically when one of its object properties get modified(overcomes OC). But we are unable to resolve BindingList in VS 2013 ultimate even though we have written using System.ComponentModel;

Answer (score 2):

You are right about that `ObservableCollection` doesn't know when its items get modified. A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27350868/how-to-update-a-value-in-parent-viewmodel-if-value-in-one-of-its-child-is-updat/27354935#27354935) and I created a generic extension method to help solve cases like this.

In your case you probably want to monitor any property changes of your item, so you can slightly modify the method to something like this -

```
public static IObservable<T> OnAnyPropertyChanges<T>(this T source)
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    return Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
            h => h.Invoke,
            h => source.PropertyChanged += h,
            h => source.PropertyChanged -= h)
        .Select(_ => source);
}
```

And to use it -

```
Observable.Merge(YourCollection.Select(c => c.OnAnyPropertyChanges()))
    .Subscribe((c) =>
    {
        // notified! do whatever you like here
    });
```

Comment: We created a static class which contains OnAnyPropertyChanges. Where should we call this method? inside setter of textboxes(which changes according to user's input) OR when Observalble collection is first initialed?

Comment: You can call my second piece of code after the `ObservableCollection` is first initialized.

Comment: You need to make your question clearer on what you are actually trying to do. When you say user edits width thru UI, what is this width? Is it a property or what?

Comment: We are editing width and height to actually alter row spanning and column spanning of variable sized wrap grid(VSWG). Initially when we initialize Observable collection, PrepareContainerForItemOverride(overriden method) is called automatically for each object in list. But now when we edit width or height property, list doesn't update and hence VSWG also doesn't update layout. **Now if we call your method after list initialization, list doesn't update** when any property changes(user edits width through UI).

Comment: Our code is at (https://https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=63F85C0B0651BFBD!114&authkey=!ALzj5Q7N22ZRuCg&ithint=file%2czip)

Comment: I'm not gonna read your code, you need to reword your OP and tell us EXACTLY what your problem is.

Comment: As and when we edit width and height in list, corresponding row and column spanning should change for that image in variable size wrap grid. For this to happen, our list should get update as soon as width or height changes. So we used your recognized method to notify list. But that is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67900/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-vaibhav).

Comment: We have listview DataTemplate having textboxes for Width and Height (Width and Height are properties defined in model class).The OC of Model class is bound to both Listview and VariableSizedWrapGrid(it shows images perfectly first time in VSRG).Now we want to dynamically change image Width and Height (Row/Column span of VariableSizedWrapGrid)according to the input provided in Width/Height textboxes of ListView. Currently when Height /Width values are getting changed,the ObservableCollection is not getting changed so the layout for VariableSizedWrapGrid is also not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` WILL update automatically any property you've bind it against. There is no need for `ObservableCollection` to raise any events.

The binding takes advatange of `INotifyPropertyChanged` and updates the necessary `TextBoxes`.

Comment: Eelemaa : We do not want listview to update automatially. we want observableCollection to get updated.